# print line number in android multiline EditText

Tags: android, code-editor

I'm creating a code editor in android. I want to print line number on the screen when each time user takes a new line. I'm using `EditText` for editor. Can any one help me out.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getLineCount()` [from here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) and auto add(as example in loop) line number for every new line.

Pseudo code:

```
for (a = 1; a < getLineCount();a++)
{
     line[a] = a.toString()+": " + line[a];
}
```

**Edit:**
For auto adding line number you should create your own implemenation of `EditText` class.

Comment: @aleung Yes, for auto add he should create his own EditText class.